# How to check negative values in mysql and decide the output after that

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using a mysql case for some calculation and my demand is that if the output is negative then i will show 0 in the place of the negative column.Otherwise the positive value.

Let me post the query:

```
select 
    concat(jo.title,' (', CCP.name, ')'), PL.analyst, PL.consultant, 
    PL.csm, 
    (CASE 
         WHEN PL.productType like 'Staffing' THEN (SELECT ((DATEDIFF(PL.dateEnd, PL.dateClientEffective)) -((WEEK(PL.dateEnd) - WEEK(PL.dateClientEffective)) * 2) - (case when weekday(PL.dateEnd) = 6 then 1 else 0 end) - (case when weekday(PL.dateClientEffective) = 5 then 1 else 0 end)) as DifD) * 8 * (PL.clientBillRate-PL.payRate) ELSE (PL.salary*PL.fee)END) Value
```

Now if the value is negative, then it should show 0 else will show the original value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please check this, haven't tested yet.

Note: this might not be the best solution

```
 select concat(jo.title,' (', CCP.name, ')'), PL.analyst, PL.consultant, PL.csm, 
if(
(CASE WHEN PL.productType like 'Staffing' THEN (SELECT ((DATEDIFF(PL.dateEnd, PL.dateClientEffective)) -((WEEK(PL.dateEnd) - WEEK(PL.dateClientEffective)) * 2) - 
(case when weekday(PL.dateEnd) = 6 then 1 else 0 end) - 
(case when weekday(PL.dateClientEffective) = 5 then 1 else 0 end)) as DifD) * 8 * (PL.clientBillRate-PL.payRate) ELSE (PL.salary*PL.fee)END)
 < 0,0,
(CASE WHEN PL.productType like 'Staffing' THEN (SELECT ((DATEDIFF(PL.dateEnd, PL.dateClientEffective)) -((WEEK(PL.dateEnd) - WEEK(PL.dateClientEffective)) * 2) - 
(case when weekday(PL.dateEnd) = 6 then 1 else 0 end) - 
(case when weekday(PL.dateClientEffective) = 5 then 1 else 0 end)) as DifD) * 8 * (PL.clientBillRate-PL.payRate) ELSE (PL.salary*PL.fee)END)
 ) Value
```

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way is simply to use `greatest()`:

```
select greatest(<expression>, 0) as col
```

It is unclear what column/expression you want to do this for in your query.  But, you can just plug it in.

The advantage of this method over other methods is:

- The  only needs to appear once in the query.  Not having to duplicate code reduces the likelihood of errors.
- There is no need for a subquery.  This is an issue in MySQL only because MySQL materializes subqueries.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use SIGN() in mysql
It returns 1 as a positive value and -1 is a negative value

Example

```
SELECT SIGN(500); -- (Output is 1)
SELECT SIGN(2500); -- (Output is 1)

SELECT SIGN(-999); -- (Output is -1)
SELECT SIGN(-5); -- (Output is -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do like this :

```
 select temp.* , --all your columns  
 if(temp.value<0,0,temp.value) as Value
 from
 ( your query mentioned above) temp;
```